# Unreachable Browser Exception using Appium

Tags: appium

I am automating android app using Appium. I am getting exception while using AndroidDriver(). 
Below is the code snippet.

```
  public class Test1 {

public static AndroidDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File appDir= new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/app/");

    System.out.println(appDir);

    File app=new File(appDir,"android-debug.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();

    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,app.getAbsolutePath());

    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);

    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");

    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"My Phone");

    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION,"5.0.2");

    cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,"com.ionicframework.appsix821050" );

    cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,"com.ionicframework.appsix821050.MainActivity" );

    URL url=new URL("http:127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

    try
    {
    driver = new AndroidDriver(url, cap);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Following is the error which is found while running the above code

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure.
>       Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16
>   13:18:38'
>       System info: host: 'Mindpro1-PC', ip: '192.168.0.103', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_112'
>       Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:89)
>         at Test1.main(Test1.java:52)
>       Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:888)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:319)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:298)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
>         ... 5 more
>       Caused by: org.apache.http.HttpException: Cannot convert host to URI: http://
>         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ProxySelectorRoutePlanner.determineProxy(ProxySelectorRoutePlanner.java:185)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ProxySelectorRoutePlanner.determineRoute(ProxySelectorRoutePlanner.java:139)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:763)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:382)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
>         ... 10 more
>       Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected authority at index 7: http://
>         at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.URI.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ProxySelectorRoutePlanner.determineProxy(ProxySelectorRoutePlanner.java:183)
>         ... 14 more`

Comment: Is this the minimal code that reproduces the problem? See [mcve].

Comment: Post some server side logs